# How can I insert a list into a list at certain intervals?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I have 2 lists and I'd like to add one list into the other at intervals of 7.

In my iPython 'whos', I have:

```
Variable                      Type             Data/Info
full_links                    list             n=15
spannedcopynotags             list             n=105
```

So, I would like to add one index item from 'full_links' after every 7th index item in 'spannedcopynotags'.

'full_links' is the 15 http:// links and 'spannedcopynotags' is the description information for all of the links. Hence, the order else the link won't match the description.

Comment: So, basically you want to `zip` the two lists, just not 1:1 but 1:7?

Comment: Correct. I tried zip(full_links, spannedcopynotags), but it gave me only 2 of the indices in 'spannedcopynotags' and 15 tuples I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list.insert()` for this purpose, for example:

```
list1 = range(100)
list2 = range(10)

pos = 0
for item in list2:
    list1.insert(pos, item)
    pos += 7
```

Note that `list.insert()` would insert the items to the end of the list if the position exceeds the lengths of the list.

Comment: Accepted!, that was my first accepted answer on SO. I will accept the other question I asked as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solutions to add one `full_links` element every `step` (7) elements of `full_links`.

```
# data for testing
spannedcopynotags = range(105)
full_links = ['%c' % c for c in range(65, 65+15)]

# compute step
length = len(spannedcopynotags)
step = length/len(full_links)

# main part
result = []
for pos_links, pos_spanned in enumerate(range(0, length, step)):
    result+= spannedcopynotags[pos_spanned:pos_spanned+step] + [full_links[pos_links]]

# main part in an unreadable one-liner
result = [
    item
    for pos, link in zip(range(0, length, step), full_links)
    for item in (spannedcopynotags[pos:pos+step] + [link])
]
```

Expected result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'A', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 'B', 14, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the `for` loop is the simplest, most understandable way. There are advantages to using `zip`, however:

- It doesn't modify the input lists
- It is easier to correctly deal with important differences in lengths of the lists

Here's an example of how you can use `zip` in this case:

```
x = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstu')
y = list('123')
it_x = iter(x)
result = [
    item for items in zip(it_x, it_x, it_x, it_x, it_x, it_x, y) 
    for item in items
]
```

To see how this works, consider that:

```
zip(x, x, x, x, x, x, x, y)
```

would be equivalent to:

```
zip(iter(x), iter(x), iter(x), iter(x), iter(x), iter(x), iter(x), y)
```

By creating the iterator yourself, and using the same one 7 times instead of independent ones, you always get the next item, instead of the same item 7 times.

To shorten it a bit, you can use argument unpacking:

```
composition = 7*[iter(x)] + [y]
result = [item for items in zip(*composition] for item in items]
```

and if you don't like the double list comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain
result = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*composition)))
```

<s>Strictly speaking all this relies on an implementation detail of `zip`, that items from its arguments are grabbed in order, but it works and is not unlikely to change.</s> The documentation reads that the evaluation order this relies on is guaranteed.

Comment: Interesting, thank you Thiijs Van Dien. I will try this as I like using 'zip' and list comprehensions when possible.